# How to sort a list by a given and specific order?

Tags: bash, sorting, awk, sed, grep

I have an hypothetical list:

```
C1
C2
H3
H4
O5
```

and, I want to sort it by introducing a specific order, **ordered by line number**, let say:

```
5
3
1
2
4
```

The output would be:

```
O5
H3
C1
C2
H4
```

My first attempt was to use the [sort](http://www.skorks.com/2010/05/sort-files-like-a-master-with-the-linux-sort-command-bash/) command in bash.

- Is this posible with awk, sed or grep ?

Comment: add the attempted command to question... so you want to sort numerically on 2nd character?

Comment: then awk would be better choice... I don't think it is possible with sort

Comment: you'll have to add your own attempt to solve first...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an `awk` solution,

```
$ cat > list
C1
C2
H3
H4
O5
$ cat > order
5
3
1
2
4
$ awk 'NR==FNR{a[FNR]=$1;next} {print a[$1]}' list order
O5
H3
C1
C2
H4
```

Brief explanation,

- `NR==FNR{a[FNR]=$1;next}`: set the `$1` for each record in list into the array element `a[FNR]`
- `print a[$1]`: for `$1` in each record in the file `order`, print corresponding `a[$1]`. In this case, the order would be kept.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ cat >list
C1
C2
H3
H4
O5
$ cat >order
5
3
1
2
4


 join -j 1 <(paste order <(seq 1 5)|sort -n) <(paste <(seq 1 5) list)|sort -n -k2|cut -d' ' -f3
```

Comment: OK, let me use simpler commands. I have a file `onetofive` where I write the line number on every line. Then I permute the line numbers by the `order`, so that line 1 goes in line 5, line 2 goes in line 3, etc.: `paste order onetofive|sort -n >permutation`. Then I paste the `permutation` beside the `list` and sort by the permutation column `paste permutation list|sort -n -k2`. Also look into `man sort` and `man paste` to understand the commands.

Answer (score 1):

If the lists are not huge, this is the kind of thing that perl does easily 
 and quickly:

```
$ cat > list
C1
C2
H3
H4
O5
$ cat > order
5
3
1
2
4
$ perl -e 'open(F,"order")||die;while(<F>){$m{$_}=$n++};\
  print sort{$m{substr($a,1)}<=>$m{substr($b,1)}} <>' < list
O5
H3
C1
C2
H4
```